# what's the difference between Redirect and Response in laravel

Tags: laravel

In my project, I need to set a cookie, here is my first version:

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('from_app', 1);
$view = View::make('buy.sale')->with(array(
        'goods' =>$goods_group,
        'time'  =>$time,
        ))->withCookie($cookie);
```

and I found that this cookie doesn't work.
and then here is the second version:

```
return Redirect::to($view)->withCookie($cookie)
```

and the cookie works but it will jump twice .
when I use

```
return Response::to($view)->withCookie($cookie)
```

everything is ok.

Comment: Response: returns a certain response (html, json, plain text, file and so on and so forth) while Redirect sends a header with a url to redirect the user to some other url (not a view!!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Laravel are you using but on mine `4.2.15` there's not such thing like `Response::to` there's only `Redirect::to` and it creates a new redirect response to the given path.